# how to pass the dropdown value in foreach in controller in codigniter

Tags: php

hello m having trouble here it always display error don't know why please help me 
i want to insert same only difference in user_id  and section_id like this

```
from_id = 1 , assigned_for = 8 , user_id = 2, section_id = 1, month= january
from_id = 1 , assigned_for = 8 , user_id = 3, section_id = 3, month= january
from_id = 1 , assigned_for = 8 , user_id = 4, section_id = 4, month= january
from_id = 1 , assigned_for = 8 , user_id = 5, section_id = 5, month= january
```

In view file

Dropdown for months.
Dropdown for select employee.
heading Allow permissions along with only names 
sections with checkbox along with dropdown of names comming from  heading Allow permissions.

Controller function

```
 $from = $this->_user['user_id'];
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            if ($select_section_ids) {
                foreach ($select_section_ids as $id) {$data = array(
                                'from_id' => $from,
                                'assigned_for' =>$this->input->post('assigned_for') ,
                                'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_names'),
                                'section_id' => $id,
                                'month' => $this->input->post('month'),
                            );

            $this->my_model->insert($data);
}}
```

'from_id' - is the loggin id
 'assigned_for' - comming from dropdown of select employee
 'user_id' - comming from dropdown of name from allow permissions
 'section_id' - comming from checkbox
 'month'-    from dropdown

how to insert this m having error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Comment: check your input name attribuite is it correct for `$this->input->post('user_names')`, this name is fine `user_names`?

Comment: also use isset() for input values either set or not

Comment: it always display Column 'user_id' cannot be null before this i used
$this->input->post('names'),
but still same error

Comment: what is the name of your input field? `names` ? or `user_names` ? and it can't be null, u always having user id right?

Comment: yes it displaying null  (`from_id`, `assigned_for`, `user_id`, `section_id`, `month`) VALUES ('1', '9', NULL, '1', 'September') because it is an single insert i want it if their are two section and two user id then insert two rows

Comment: first of all check `print_r($_POST)` what are u getting? before `foreach()`

Comment: Array
(
    [month] => June
    [assigned_for] => 6
    [section_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 5
        )

    [team_leads] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 6
        )

)

Comment: `team_leads` is equal to users???

Comment: team_leads is the user_id

Comment: check answer. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong index name for user id, `team_lead` is an array and equal to `section_ids` so you can use $key of `section_ids` for getting correct `team_leads`.

**Example:**

```
<?php
foreach ($select_section_ids as $key => $id) {
  $data = array(
    'from_id' => $from,
    'assigned_for' => (isset($_POST['assigned_for']) ? $_POST['assigned_for'] : 0),
    'user_id' => $_POST['team_leads'][$key], // this will use the key of section_ids, which is equal to team_leads.
    'section_id' => $id,
    'month' => $_POST['month'],
);
?>
```

Also note that, if `team_leads` is not equal to `section_ids`, than you must need to add check like that:

```
'user_id' => isset($_POST['team_leads'][$key]) ? $_POST['team_leads'][$key] : 0,
```

Comment: glad to help u, @Ghugu

Comment: 'assigned_for' => (isset($_POST['assigned_for']) ? $_POST['assigned_for'] : 0),
     'user_id' => $_POST['team_leads'][$key]
please explain me how they work

Comment: `$_POST['assigned_for']` if this value is empty or not set , u can store 0 value of ignore this one , u can use as u are using before... @Ghugu

Comment: @Ghugu: for `$_POST['team_leads'][$key]`  if you note team_leads and section_ids having same no of indexes, you can use section_ids key for getting team_leads

Comment: @Ghugu: i suggest u to read ARRAY and associative arrays, keys, multi dimensional array.